# I want to play audio from my Mac over WiFi speakers without having to install a bunch of apps

Tags: wifi, audio

I'm probably overthinking this but here goes.

Seems like all of the WiFi speakers I see for sale are pushing bundles of apps. Screw that. I want a 'dumb' set of wireless speakers. I don't want "smart home" nonsense.

I mainly listen to youtube in a browser on my Mac mini and I want to be able to hear it in my kitchen, den, etc. I have a standalone wireless access point set up already.

Which vendor is the least intrusive or most bare-bones in their approach?

Comment: When you say wireless, I presume you do not mean bluetooth? If not, why not just grab a bluetooth speaker? Is the range not good enough? Do you need to be able to control your music from the speaker or something?

Comment: Don't know how readily available such things are these days, but I've got some old (analogue) wireless speakers that came with a small transmitter. I use them for sending TV audio to the kitchen, but would work just as well for computer audio.

Comment: It's not about controlling a music playlist for me. It's about a youtube or youtube channels.

Comment: Yes, bluetooth is not going to have the range. Also, I hate bluetooth :)

Comment: The newer Bluetooth are better than many WiFi - not perfect and interference can be an issue, but check these https://www.lifewire.com/best-bluetooth-audio-receivers-4138227

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AirPlay Speakers**

The easiest experience is to get AirPlay 2 compatible speakers and you have zero app, native OS support, works everywhere experience.

- https://www.imore.com/best-airplay-2-speakers
- https://www.apple.com/ios/home/accessories/#section-speaker

The airplay page and marketing logo explain why this takes away the need for any apps, and is strictly controlled to make your experience better.

- https://www.apple.com/airplay/

[image]

I get you might consider this smart home, but for sound the setup and reliability are amazing and for me worth the cost.

**AirPlay Adapter**

Alternatively, you can get a cheap AirPlay adapter and connect it to existing speakers. This gives you all the benefits of AirPlay without high cost of AirPlay speakers. You can connect to any existing speakers you have that take an aux input. The adapter connects to your WiFi network at home, and allows any Apple device in the house to stream music to your speakers.

- [Example adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06WRSXVBR)

**Bluetooth Adapter**

Also available without AirPlay - a dumb setup is going to be a $35 or less Bluetooth receiver to powered analog input speakers.

- [Logitech Bluetooth Audio Adapter for Bluetooth Streaming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IQBSW28)
- [whichever studio monitors your heart desires](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1449258-REG/mackie_cr4ltd_cr4_4_multimedia_reference.html)

Comment: If you have an existing speaker setup you like there are also Airplay adapters, which connect to Wifi in your house to play music from anywhere. Something like this is cheap, and gives you all the AirPlay advantages with existing speakers: https://www.amazon.com/M5-Audiocast-iHeartRadio-Supporting-Supported/dp/B06WRSXVBR

Comment: @Alex These devices are insanely powerful. Serious bitrates and channels supported, digital toslink audio, small size, very low cost. Thanks for that link. Feel free to edit a WiFi option into my answer body if you feel you really can recommend one based on experience.

Comment: I'm not much interested in listening to music. I like listening to people on youtube talk about politics. science etc.